# Why there is giving a error message while using msgbox command in visual basic in visual studio 2019?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, frameworks

I am getting an error while using msgbox command in visual basic .net in visual studio 2019 community version .
The error is saying that msgbox is not declared or it is inaccessible due to its protection level.

Please help me to correct this error.
I have downloaded all the required libraries for visual basics.

Comment: You need to show us how you are “using msgbox command”. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69060475/edit) your question to include the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're missing an `Imports` at the top of the file. Likely you want:

```vb
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

Alternatively, your project might not be referencing the right assemblies for the `MessageBox` type to be found.

Can you share the contents of your source code and project file, by editing your question to include more details?

Comment: Yes thanks now its working by importing it